# Properly Implementing __lt__

Tags: python

I'm trying to store instances of this class in a heap from the heapq module. But when I attempt to push a Node I get `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Node' and 'Node'` I added `__gt__` and
`total_ordering` which gives the error `ValueError: must define at least one ordering operation: < > <= >=`. Is there something incorrect about the comparison implementations?

```
@total_ordering
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, edgeCost=0, parent=None):
        self.name = name
        self.cost = edgeCost
        self.parent = parent

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.cost > other.cost

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cost < other.cost

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Node) and self.cost == other.cost

    def path(self):
        path = []
        node = self
        while node:
            path.append(node.name)
        return reversed(path)

    def addNode(self, name, edgeCost=0):
        return Node(name, edgeCost + self.cost, self)
```

edit:

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, name, neighbors={}, heuristic=0):
        self.name = name
        self.neighbors = neighbors
        self.heuristic = heuristic
        self.node = None

    def getWeight(self, neighbor):
        return self.neighbors[neighbor]

    def neighbors(self):
        return iter(self.neighbors)

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def searchNode(self, cost, parent):
        self.node = Node(self.name, cost, parent)
        return self.node

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, graph={}):
        self.vertices = graph

    def addVertex(self, name, neighbors={}, heuristic=0):
        vertex = Vertex(name, neighbors, heuristic)
        self.vertices.update({name: vertex})

    def getVertex(self, name):
        return self.vertices[name]

    def getVertices(self):
        return self.vertices
```

This is the only other thing I thought might be relevant. But total_ordering throws the ValueError when I import the file.

```
def greedy(graph, start, end):
    fringe = []
    visited = set()
    node = mylib.Node(start)
    heapq.heappush(fringe, node)

    while fringe:
        if node.name == end:
            return node.path
        node = heapq.heappop(fringe)
        current = graph.getVertex(node.name)
        visited.add(current)

        for neighbor in current.neighbors:
            vertex = graph.getVertex(neighbor)
            if vertex not in visited and vertex.node not in fringe:
                newNode = vertex.searchNode(current.neighbors[vertex.name], current.node)
                heapq.heappush(fringe, newNode)
            elif vertex.node in fringe:
                tmp = fringe[fringe.index(vertex.node)]
                if tmp.cost < vertex.node.cost:
                    newNode = vertex.searchNode(vertex.name, current.neighbor[vertex.name], current.node)
                    fringe.remove(vertex.node)
                    heapq.heappush(fringe, newNode)
```

The main file

```
import mylib


def main():
    graph = mylib.Graph()
    graph.addVertex("a", {"b": 2, "c": 2}, 5)
    graph.addVertex("b", {"a": 2, "d": 1}, 7)
    graph.addVertex("c", dict(zip(("a", "d", "f"), (2, 8, 3))), 4)
    graph.addVertex("d", dict(zip(("s", "b", "c", "e"), (3, 1, 8, 2))), 7)
    graph.addVertex("e", dict(zip(("s", "d", "h", "r"), (9, 2, 8, 2))), 5)
    graph.addVertex("f", dict(zip(("c", "r", "g"), (3, 2, 2))), 2)
    graph.addVertex("g", {"f": 2}, 2)
    graph.addVertex("h", dict(zip(("e", "p", "q"), (8, 4, 4))), 11)
    graph.addVertex("p", dict(zip(("s", "h", "q"), (1, 4, 4))), 14)
    graph.addVertex("q", dict(zip(("h", "p"), (4, 15))), 12)
    graph.addVertex("r", dict(zip(("e", "f"), (2, 2))), 3)
    graph.addVertex("s", dict(zip(("d", "e", "p"), (3, 9, 1))), 14)
    print(mylib.greedy(graph, "s", "g"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(indentation is correct in original)

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? Are you sure you didn't accidentally write two `Node` classes?

Comment: It's python 3. And yes, there's only one.

Comment: what is @totalordering decorator exactly doing?

Comment: I see issues here (for example, forgetting to return `NotImplemented`, and never changing `node` inside `path`), but nothing that would cause the behavior you describe. Please post something that runs and demonstrates the TypeError (or the ValueError) when you run it.

Comment: The node class works properly for me, I sorted a list of nodes, and compare two nodes.

Comment: It's from functools. It's supposed to implement the rest of the comparison operators if you provide one. @DiegoContreras

Comment: I see more issues in your Vertex class, such as the mutable default argument and the fact that `self.neighbors = neighbors` hides the `neighbors` method, but we still need something that **runs** and **demonstrates the error when run**.

Comment: Psychic debugging: You're modifying the module and `reload`ing it occasionally, adding new `Node`s from the new definition each time. Except each `reload` produces a unique version of `Node`, and some of the old ones don't have a `__lt__`. Because as written, your `__lt__` is fine, as is your use of `total_ordering`. Close your interpreter, and try again from scratch; this code should work.

Comment: Strip it down, in a way that leaves the result runnable. Throw a few nodes in a heap and see if that's enough to trigger the TypeError, or if you're still getting the ValueError, see if you can produce a file containing just the Node class and the necessary imports for Node and see if that triggers the ValueError on its own. You don't need to post your entire program; you need to post something that reproduces the error.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry. I read that late. I'll do that now.

Comment: "indentation is correct in original" - that suggests you don't know how to format code on Stack Overflow, which suggests you may have changed your indentation without realizing it when initially posting your `Node` class. It is likely that one or more of your methods is actually defined nested inside another method in your original code. If so, fix that.

Comment: As for how to format code on Stack Overflow, copy-paste the code from a source file into the question box, then select the parts you pasted (including the parts that look okay in the preview) and hit Ctrl-K.

Comment: @user2357112 I just didn't know a quick way to indent all those lines quickly. But you are correct. That's embarrassing. I somehow managed to nest everything in __init__. Thanks. Should I just delete this?

Comment: @jocal17 but I cannot reproduce your issue with the code above.